# Count - SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I have the below query which brings 71965 rows ( includes duplicates).

```
SELECT
(REPLACE([DATE],'-','') + '_' + [Championship] + '_' + [Home_Team] + '_Vs_'+ [Away_Team]) 
FROM
[Soccer_Database].[dbo].[Ext_Match_Details]
```

With the below query i m trying to `Count` how many times each value appears (to find duplicates).

```
SELECT
(REPLACE([     DATE],'-','') + '_' + [Championship] + '_' + [Home_Team] + '_Vs_'+ [Away_Team]) ,
COUNT(REPLACE([DATE],'-','') + '_' + [Championship] + '_' + [Home_Team] + '_Vs_'+ [Away_Team]) AS COUNT
FROM
    [Soccer_Database].[dbo].[Ext_Match_Details]
GROUP BY
    (REPLACE([DATE],'-','') + '_' + [Championship] + '_' + [Home_Team] + '_Vs_'+ [Away_Team])
```

BUT i get 71958 (the numbers of rows without the duplicates) and in all rows `Count` column is 1.
Any help?

Comment: Show sample data.

Comment: There is no NULL fields. That fields don t allows NULLS

Comment: Can you please add some sample duplicate data from the output of your first query?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I manage to find a solution. My query was correct, because there are duplicates so the reduced number of rows are correct. I have add  'order by' as 'desc' and i get the rows which are duplicates.

Comment: That is what I provided as a solution. Could you please mark it as accepted so this question closes.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end:
`HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`
to filter the groups which have more than one row (= duplicates).
If you want to see all rows, then add instead
`ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC`
to bring the duplicates on top. This works as it is not true that all your COUNTs are 1 - there is a difference in the row count of your original query and with the `GROUP BY` as you explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (REPLACE([DATE],'-','') + '_' + [Championship] + '_' + [Home_Team] + '_Vs_'+ [Away_Team]) as [Value] 
            , count(1) as [Count]
    FROM [Soccer_Database].[dbo].[Ext_Match_Details]
    group by (REPLACE([DATE],'-','') + '_' + [Championship] + '_' + [Home_Team] + '_Vs_'+ [Away_Team])
```

Comment: Please try sum(1) in replacement of count(1).